# vue js axios response to array list

Tags: vue.js, axios

i am working a typeahead. and my typeahead accept a array list like ['Canada', 'USA', 'Mexico'].
and now i have a axios api to get a list of country. but i don't know how can i convert to a array list. Now work if hardcode a country list.

```
<vue-bootstrap-typeahead
 :data="addresses"
 v-model="addressSearch"
/>
data() {
 return {
  addresses: ['Canada', 'USA', 'Mexico'],
  addressSearch: '',
 }
},
axios.get('api_link', {})
  .then(function (response) {
  //How can i create a array list from api return useing name like addresses?
})
```

And my api return:
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Canada"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "USA"
        },
    ]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make use of the `created()` lifecycle hook to get the data:

```
created() {
  axios.get('api_link', {})
    .then((response) => { this.addresses = response.data.map(x => x.name) })
}
```

In your data() make sure to initialize to an empty array:

```
data() {
  return {
    addresses: [],
    ...
}
```

Just so you see what the `map` function does:

```js
console.log([ { "id": 1, "name": "Canada" }, { "id": 2, "name": "USA" }, ].map(x=>x.name))
```

Comment: and now, my api return [ { "id": 1, "name": "Canada" ,"name2": "Canada2" }, { "id": 2, "name": "USA" "name2": "USA2" }, ]
how can i convert to ['Canada', 'Canada2', 'USA', 'USA2']??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.map` to take only the names like this:

```
axios.get('api_link', {})
  .then((response) => {
    this.addresses = response.data.map(country => country.name)
  })
```